# Are url helpers only for views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a mailer I am trying to do this:

```
def registartion

..

   @login_url = login_users_path(@path)

..

end
```

**But it is throughing an error, and it doesn't work in console either.
'undefined method login_users_path...'**

Comment: Have you run rake routes and confirmed that it's there in the first place?

Comment: To use helpers in the Rails console, use `app.helper_method`, for example, `app.login_users_path`. But this isn't the answer to your problem, see my answer ^_^

Answer (score 2):

See [**Generating URLs in Action Mailer views**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views) in the Action Mailer guide. Emphasis in the last paragraph mine (that's the part that should fix your problem):

> URLs can be generated in mailer views using `url_for` or named routes.
>
> Unlike controllers, the mailer instance doesn’t have any context about the incoming request so you’ll need to provide the `:host`, `:controller`, and `:action`:
>
> ```
> <%= url_for(:host => "example.com",
>             :controller => "welcome",
>             :action => "greeting") %>
> ```
>
> When using named routes you only need to supply the `:host`:
>
> ```
> <%= user_url(@user, :host => "example.com") %>
> ```
>
> **Email clients have no web context and so paths have no base URL to form complete web addresses. Thus, when using named routes only the “_url” variant makes sense.**

Answer (score 0):

Brandon answered this question, but for future reference:

**As a tip to access routes in the console:**

To access the routes in console you can use the following format:

```
app.{insert_route_here}
```

so in your case:

```
app.login_users_path
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to @Brandon Tilley's answer, you can avoid having to specify the `:host` if you define in (for development) `environments/development.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

Then you can do:

```
@login_url = login_users_url(@path)
```

You want to use fully-qualified URLs (http://example.com/something) instead of relative paths (/something) in your emails!

Comment: so in production I will need that setting also?

Comment: Yes, but in `production.rb` it will be the actual site address, eg. example.com instad of localhost:3000.

Comment: yes, I just don't want to have to modify so many files when I don't have to, I think I'll put it in my main sites config, thanks!